# How does Oracle database decides if a table is small?

Tags: oracle, query-optimization, database-administration, sqlperformance, oracle19c

When I read about query performance in Oracle, I see the term "Small Table" many times. For example, one says, Oracle uses the sort-merge join only when the table is small.
So, is there any formula that the database server uses if the table is small, or is there any number of rows, etc?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context. In terms of sort-merge join, it's not so much that the table is small according to some pre-defined formula, but rather the optimizer makes a cost-based decision. As it turns out, a small table is more likely to end up with a lower cost compared to other plans.
There is also the notion of "small table threshold". This is the size of the table (or segment, strictly speaking), for which a portion of the buffer cache is used to read a table. This is calculated as 2% of the buffer cache size. You may see an execution plan that uses small table replication instead of broadcast, if the table fits into the small table threshold.